# mapbox expression string generation

Tags: javascript, expression, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to pass different rgba colors to different points in mapbox. I added a `realiveOpacity` property to each dot and would like to generate the correct color string from its data. I tried both expression but I guess the syntax is somehow wrong. How would it go correctly?

`'circle-color': ["string", "rgba(255, 0, 0, ['get', 'realiveOpacity'])"]`

`["string", "rgba(255, 0, 0,"+ ['get', 'realiveOpacity'] + " )"]`

This Constructor works:
`["string", "rgba(255, 0, 0,0.5"]`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rgba-function:

> Creates a color value from red, green, blue components, which must
>   range between 0 and 255, and an alpha component which must range
>   between 0 and 1. If any component is out of range, the expression is
>   an error.
>
> ["rgba", number, number, number, number]: color
>
> https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#expressions-rgba

```
"circle-color": ["rgba", 255, 0, 0, ["get", "realiveOpacity"]]
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/tjh4u0f6/ ]

Comment: Could you still give an example how to solve this via string? There might be other use cases where I'll want to create strings.

Comment: You can use `concat` function: `["concat", "rgba(", "255,", "0,", "0,", ["get", "realiveOpacity"], ")"]` - https://jsfiddle.net/uhw7dncj/